# Pipe for complex json in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a complex json as below:

```js
 dashboardMenu:[  
   {  
      category:'Physical Inventory',
      subCategory:[  
         {  
            'subcategory':'Upload PI Count Schedule',
            'icon':'glyphicon-time',
            'shortcode':'A1',
            'router':'/physical-inventory/PIUpload'
         },
         {  
            'subcategory':'Review PI Count Schedule',
            'icon':'glyphicon-list-alt',
            'shortcode':'B1',
            'router':'/physical-inventory/PIReview'
         },
         {  
            'subcategory':'Manage PI Group',
            'icon':'glyphicon-wrench',
            'shortcode':'B1',

         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      category:'Notification Management',
      subCategory:[  
         {  
            'subcategory':'Create Notification',
            'icon':'glyphicon-envelope',
            'shortcode':'A1',
            'router':'/notification-management/createNotification'
         },
         {  
            'subcategory':'Review Notification',
            'icon':'glyphicon-list-alt',
            'shortcode':'B1'
         }
      ]
```

I want to add pipe which will filter out data on the basis of Category, subcategory.
I have managed to filter out the data from category but i am not able to filter data from subcategory.
Pipe -

```js
if (stringToSearch !== undefined)

return items
.filter(item => 
  item.category.toLowerCase().indexOf(stringToSearch) !== -1 || item.category.toLowerCase().indexOf(stringToSearch) !== -1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to get items, which contains one of subcategory try this:

```
return items.filter((item) => { 
   const filtered = item.subCategory.filter((sub) => {
      return sub.subcategory.toLowerCase().indexOf(stringToSearch) > -1;
   });
   return item.category.toLowerCase().indexOf(stringToSearch) > -1 || filtered.length;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working fine for one of the subcategory, I have to search either  by category or by subcategory .

Comment: @Akanksha so you have to add logical OR to return. I edited my answer to show you.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help . But is there a way to filter out that particular subcategory. Currently i am getting all other subcategores along as well. for example if i search for Upload PI Count i should get Physical Inventory and then only Upload PI Count subactegory